# How clear UIWebView cache

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, browser-cache

How to clear the cache of a UIWebView?

I am making a simple application (with only three buttons (back, forward, refresh) and a UIWebView) and I realized that in my Documents & Data iPhone gets a very high value of Cache. I already looked at various documents and posts (even here at StackOverflow) but none solved the problem.
If you need lines of codes, ask.

Answer (score 6):

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
```

This would remove a cached response for a specific request. There is also a call that will remove all cached responses for all requests ran on the UIWebView:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

After that, you can try deleting any associated cookies with the UIWebView:

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Comment: method in which I will have to put these codes (that is what Naoe did until now )

Answer (score 0):

its so simple

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```