# Limit the cache size from WebView on iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, uiwebview, browser-cache

**Here's my edited question:**

How can I limit cache size from WebView on iOS app?

Can I use one of these codes?

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:X];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:X];
```

Or is there a possibility to clear cache by clicking a button?

Comment: There are various posts that describe how you can remove UIWebView's chache. Such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054472/how-clear-uiwebview-cache) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523435/how-to-clear-uiwebview-cache)  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache)

Comment: Your edited question is completely different than the original one and this makes Hugo's answer out of context. Please roll-back the question and consider asking this as a different / new question.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to clear `UIWebview` cache is:**

> **Objective-C**

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

> **Swift**

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

> Now, for your case, you may want to use this function after
>   calculating proper date:
>
> ```
> Clears the given cache of any cached responses since the provided date.
>      */
>     @available(iOS 8.0, *)
>     public func removeCachedResponsesSinceDate(date: NSDate)
> ```

**A good scenario would be:**

1.- Store the last time/date you cleaned cache (or first time the app is used) in `NSUserDefaults`.

2.- Every time you enter your app (or in `background fetch`) calculate if has being 24h or more since that date

3.- If `true`, then clear cache and return to step 1

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me. But I'm a noob at this so I'm not able to do this. Do you have a sample code for me?

Comment: There are a lot of matters here to take into account. Try to study a little about these topics and back to me again. It would be very large to post here.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it. I've a small question: What do I have to use to limit the cache to e.g. five websites?

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:X];
or

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:X];
Will X be the number of websites or data in MB?